# Web Scrape - Can anyone assist in cleaning this up?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm fairly new when it comes to this and i've been working on this scrape of a webpage for a number of days now.  I have been actively trying to avoid asking the question but i'm seriously stuck.

My Problems

1. The location I have the span loop currently positioned it prints all the prices for each listing, each time it runs through the "for product" loop.  If I place it outside of this loop, it either prints the first in the list or the last in the list. How do I extract the price and print it along side each individual product.

I understand i've a lot of unused imports listed.  These were just various avenues I was trying and yet to remove them.

The end goal here is to either push to json or csv file (also not currently written - but have a fair idea how to approach this aspect once have data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import shutil
import csv
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame
import re
import os
import urllib
import locale
import json
from selenium import webdriver
os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/andrew.glass/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("https://www.mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d130_Beretta_Over___Under_Competeition_shotguns.html")

URL = 'https://www.mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d130_Beretta_Over___Under_Competeition_shotguns.html'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
products = soup.find_all("div", "GC62 Product")

for product in products:
#title
   title = product.find("h3") 
   titleText = title.text if title else ''

#manufacturer name
   manufacturer = product.find("div", "GC5 ProductManufacturer")
   manuText = manufacturer.text if manufacturer else ''

#image location
   img = product.find("div", "ProductImage")
   imglinks = img.find("a") if img else ''
   imglinkhref = imglinks.get('href')  if imglinks else ''
   imgurl = 'https://www.mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents'+imglinkhref
   #print(imgurl.replace('..', ''))

#description
   description = product.find("div", "GC12 ProductDescription")
   descText = description.text if description else ''

    #more description
   more = product.find("div", "GC12 ProductDetailedDescription")
   moreText = more.text if more else ''

#price - not right
   spans = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.GC20.ProductPrice span")
   for i in range(0,len(spans),2):
       span = spans[i].text
       print(span)
       i+=1 

   print(titleText)
   print(manuText)
   print(descText)
   print(moreText)
   print(imgurl.replace('..', ''))
   print("\n")
```

output:

```
£1,695.00
£1,885.00
£1,885.00
£2,015.00
£2,175.00
£2,175.00
£2,385.00
£2,115.00
£3,025.00
£3,315.00
£3,635.00
£3,925.00
£2,765.00
£3,045.00
£3,325.00
£3,615.00
£3,455.00
£2,815.00
£3,300.00
£3,000.00
£7,225.00
£7,555.00
£7,635.00
£7,015.00
£7,355.00
12G Beretta DT11 Trap Adjustable
beretta
Click on more for full details.
You may order this gun online, however due to UK Legislation we are not permitted to ship directly to you, we can however ship to a registered firearms dealer local to you. Once we receive your order, we will contact you to arrange which registered firearms dealer you would like the gun to be shipped to.




DT 11 Trap (Steelium Pro)

12

2 3/4"
10x10 rib
3/4&F

30"/32" weight; 4k
https://www.mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/media/l_dt11_02.jpg
```

Comment: You question is *at least* four separate questions. Could you please edit your post so it focuses on a *single* issue?

Comment: @baduker You are correct.  I've removed the addition issues and focusing on my current issue.

Comment: That looks better. Here's a tip: I'd first work on fixing your indentation, as it's a fundamental concept in Python.  That might possibly remediate *all* your problems.

Comment: @baduker you sneaky son of a B - thats fixed this issue

Comment: @baduker - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Comments from @baduker pointed me in the correct direction - indentations.  Thanks!

```
import requests
import shutil
import csv
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame
import re
import os
import urllib
import locale
import json
from selenium import webdriver
os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/andrew.glass/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("https://www.mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d130_Beretta_Over___Under_Competeition_shotguns.html")

URL = 'https://www.mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d130_Beretta_Over___Under_Competeition_shotguns.html'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
products = soup.find_all("div", "GC62 Product")

for product in products:
#title
    title = product.find("h3") 
    titleText = title.text if title else ''

 #manufacturer name
    manufacturer = product.find("div", "GC5 ProductManufacturer")
    manuText = manufacturer.text if manufacturer else ''

 #image location
    img = product.find("div", "ProductImage")
    imglinks = img.find("a") if img else ''
    imglinkhref = imglinks.get('href')  if imglinks else ''
    imgurl = 'https://www.mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents'+imglinkhref
    #print(imgurl.replace('..', ''))
 
#description
    description = product.find("div", "GC12 ProductDescription")
    descText = description.text if description else ''

     #more description
    more = product.find("div", "GC12 ProductDetailedDescription")
    moreText = more.text if more else ''

 #price - not right
spans = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.GC20.ProductPrice span")
for i in range(0,len(spans),2):
    span = spans[i].text
    print(span)
    i+=1 

    print(titleText)
    print(manuText)
    print(descText)
    print(moreText)
    print(imgurl.replace('..', ''))
    print("\n")
```